# Assigning to numpy structured arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to get structured data somehow into numpy structured array form. I read the little and (sorry SciPy!) sloppy documentation on this topic I could find, and still am getting nowhere.

Basically I want to do something simple like this:

```
import numpy as np

dt = [('contacts', '(2,4)f8'), 
      ('modelname', 'S10')]

arr = np.zeros((2,), dtype=dt)

testdata = [[99, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

arr[0]['contacts'] = np.array(testdata)
arr[0]['modelname'] = 'test'
print arr
```

and then I'd like to see the field 'contacts' of the structured array to be set to the desired contents.

However, the output is:

```
[([[99.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], 'test')
 ([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], '')]
```

Obviously only the first number got assigned.

Comment: I found a relevant bug issue

Answer (score 3):

You're indexing your array the wrong way round. Try:

```
 arr['contacts'][0] = np.array(testdata)
```

That is, for the `'contacts'` column of `arr`, set the row indexed at `0` to your `testdata`. When you write `arr[0]` you retreive a "record scalar". In fact, if you check, you'll see that `arr[0]` has type `numpy.void`.

Assigning to it does not affect the memory assigned to the entire record. By contrast, `arr['contacts']` creates view and assigning to `arr['contacts'][0]` in that array view modifies the original memory.

I agree the NumPy docs could be clearer on this...

Answer (score -1):

The fact that your assignment is changing just the 1st number looks buggy to me, not just an problem with documentation.

```
In [1496]: x = np.zeros((2,),dtype=('(2,3)i4,a4'))

In [1497]: x
Out[1497]: 
array([([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], b''), ([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], b'')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2, 3)), ('f1', 'S4')])
```

Buggy case where it just assigns the 1st number:

```
In [1498]: x[0]['f0'] = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)

In [1499]: x
Out[1499]: 
array([([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], b''), ([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], b'')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2, 3)), ('f1', 'S4')])
```

But adding `[:]` corrects that - it means 'replace just the data contents'

```
In [1500]: x[0]['f0'][:] = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)

In [1501]: x
Out[1501]: 
array([([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], b''), ([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], b'')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2, 3)), ('f1', 'S4')])
```

Setting the whole element with a tuple - this is described in the docs.  A list of tuples sets multiple elements.

```
In [1502]: x[0] = (np.arange(2,8).reshape(2,3),'test')

In [1503]: x
Out[1503]: 
array([([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]], b'test'), ([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], b'')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2, 3)), ('f1', 'S4')])
```

Selecting the field first also works (further evidence your case pulled up a numpy bug)

```
In [1504]: x['f0'][0] = np.arange(3,9).reshape(2,3)

In [1505]: x
Out[1505]: 
array([([[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]], b'test'), ([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], b'')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2, 3)), ('f1', 'S4')])
```

I'm not satisfied with the 'record scalar' explanation.  `x`, `x['f0']` and `x['f0']` all have the same `__array_interface__` data pointer.

`x['f0'][0]` and `x[0]['f0']` have the same `__array_interface_-` and `type`.  Both work for operations like `+=`.  The only difference, that I can find, is in that direct array assignment.  Modifying just one element of the array is just plain wrong.

Selecting the row by a slice also works fine:

```
x[:1]['f0'] = ...
```

---

Looks like this is the relevant bug issue

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3126